# Indentify the soundtrack in The Apprentice S01E05?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

I'm trying to work out what the piece of music playing from (8:54-9:20) in [The Apprentice (UK) (Series 1, Episode 5)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2L3rCoGIz4E) is called. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

It is called "Santa Maria". You may listen to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xu3AjfZyg6k).

Comment: It's part of the Shall We Dance movie soundtrack, but was not written expressly for the movie (it's from 2001, and the movie is from 2004). Here's the scene

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNjVaaZXcBY